# How do I check my map units (needed for Point Density Tool)?

Tags: arcmap, units

The Point Density Tool in ArcMap asks me to specify cell size in map units, but I am confused as to how to find out exactly what my map units are (e.g. whether they are based on the data frame coordinate system, the source coordinate system, or something else).

Where exactly do I go to check what my map units are so that I can define an appropriate cell size?

To minimize the chance of further confusion, I would ideally like specific instructions on where to locate this information within ArcMap.

Answer (score 0):

The output cell size is optional.  This is where you control the cell size of the output raster.

If you look at the information on this field in the tool, it says this is the value in the environment if specifically set.  If the environment is not set, then the cell size is the shorter of the width or height of the output extent in the output spatial reference, divided by 250.

The smaller the cell, the more refined the results, but the bigger the raster file.

Answer (score 0):

ArcMap Map Units are the Linear Unit of the Coordinate System of the Data Frame. You can see the Linear Units (and assign a Data Frame Coordinate System) from the Data Frame Properties, Coordinate System tab.

For example: a US State Plane projected coordinate system will likely have a US Foot linear measure... although some have meters.